# discord,js confusion, I want to add a status to my discord bot but my code isn't working properly, how can I make a status for my bot?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, discord.js

I tried doing already but as you can see from the picture below it didn't work how can I fix it?
[image: code here]
[image: what discord shows]

Comment: Feedback: Don't post images of text. Post the actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the client's activity would require the keyword `activity` instead of `game`

So, for example:

```
client.user.setPresence({
    activity: {
        name: 'Using -help',
        type: 'STREAMING',
        url: 'https://www.twitch.tv/yournamehere'
    },
    status: 'online',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it also like this:

```
client.user.setActivity("Using -help", {type: "STREAMING", url: "Your Twitch URL"});
```

If a user now clicks on the `Watch` button, in your bots profile, he will get to your provided Twitch URL.